# laravel 5.2 vendor publish not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I try to load file vendor in my ressource folder for change pagination code. 
When i try the php artisan like this

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

I have this message that tells me that it worked well

> Publishing complete for tag []!

but i have noting vendor folder en my ressource forlder.
I try this but not work

```
php artisan config:clear
```

and

```
composer dump-autoload -o
php artisan vendor:publish --force
```

Comment: It will not go to resources folder it will got to the app/config directory if it publish anything.

Comment: when i check the laravel doc for pagination , the documentation says to make a php artisan vendor:publish and after there is a vendor file in the resource folder to modify the paginations

Comment: try composer install(update) after that composer dump-autoload  and after that php artisan vendor:publish

Comment: i try composer install and update and composer dump-autoload but i still do not have the vendor file that appears but I have my app/config folder is update and my page pagination work I'm just unable to style it

Comment: I find responce. For laravel 5,2 vendor:publish not work for pagination  it is introduced on 5.3